# Degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, substitution

I looked at some exercises from Dummit and Foote, which cover degree of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}})$, when $a^{2} - b$ is a square in the ground field, but here, $a^{2} - b = -1$, so these results don't apply. However, I think I may have found the minimal polynomial just by playing with it: $x^{4} - 2x^{2} - 1$. How do I show this is irreducible though? Or is it not, in fact?

Comment: It depends on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Right, so in this case $a = 1$, $b = 2$. I just edited the post to add that I found a candidate for the minimal polynomial by playing around, but I need to show it's irreducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $x=y+1$ and Eisenstein's criterion.

Answer (score 2):

A standard way to prove that a general polynomial of degree 4 is irreducible is to show that it has no roots in the base field, then suppose it decomposes into polynomials of degree 2 so compute:

$$ x^4-2x^2-1 = (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$

and show that there are no solutions $a,b,c,d$ in the base field.

Comment: It seems like that could be time-consuming though. Michael's suggestion works quickly in this case.

Comment: It is. If you are in $\mathbb{Q}$ always try applying Eisenstein's before doing something of this sort (unless you have access to a computer).